# How to scroll to a text in Appium/Selenium in Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, appium-android

I am using appium for android automation using python language.
I am stuck on problem where I need to scroll the view till certain text is found.
I am using swipe method by using coordinates, but I need to scroll via text.
In this any method.

Comment: Can you paste your actual code? Have you searched for info?

Comment: yes, I have searched info with it, tries everything. execute_script, select method, TouchActions method..everything. Doesn't work at all.